# update database without changing the picture

Tags: java

When I update the data in database but not touching the image it will always like this "image can't be null" but the image is there..when i set my database to "YES", "NULL" it save but the picture there is gone..how to solve this can some one help me?

here is my code in update

```
try {

                String value1 = txt_StudentNumber.getText();
                String value2 = txt_FullName.getText();
                String value3 = txt_email.getText();



           //pst.setBytes(5,person_image);
                String sql = " update students_records set Student_Id='" + value1 + "' ,Full_Name ='" + value2 + "' ,Email ='" + value3 + "', Course=?,Gender=?,Image=?,Date=?  where Student_Id='" + value1 + "' ";

                pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                String tmp =(String) Course_cmb.getSelectedItem();
                pst.setString(1, tmp);
                 if(male.isSelected())
                {
                    gender="MALE";
                }
                if(female.isSelected())
                {
                    gender="FEMALE";
                }
                pst.setString(2, gender);
                pst.setBytes(3, person_image);

                java.sql.Timestamp date = new java.sql.Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime());
                    pst.setTimestamp(4, date);

                pst.executeUpdate();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Updated");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            }

            Update_table();
            this.dispose();
        }
```

Comment: Is **person_image** a byte[] array? Does it contain anything other than null?

Comment: Why do you sometimes use question marks and sometimes do direct substitution in your UPDATE String?  Substitute all of the values using question marks.

Comment: person_image is a byte[]..nope it contains only the image cant be null but it is have a picture...

Comment: Thanks i will change my code to question mark all and see what will happen. Its this affecting my code not to work properly? What is the good practice to use in that can you help me